# NDjango throws TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ndjango

I'm just trying to get started with NDjango but am having issues running a basic test app. When running the page in either debug or release the following exception is thrown:

Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerMessageAttribute' from assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

This is thrown when the NDjangoHandle is created in the HttpApplication ctor. The fsharp assemblies are definitely all there in the gac (and they seem to be distributed with NDjango too) so I'm a bit confused about this one. Googling this turns up zip.

I'm using NDjango 0.9.7.0 for .NET 4.0 in vis studio 2010

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install [FSharpPowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)? I am not sure if it was stated clear enough in the installation package but it is required and it does not come with the standard installation.

Also - by any chance do you have a side by side installation of VS2010/VS2008? The FSharp installation package has a [bug](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13145.aspx) which can cause similar problems

Let me know if you need further help. You can communicate with us directly through [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/ndjango/issues/list) and/or [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ndjango-dev/?pli=1)

Comment: That's the badger. I didn't have the powerpack installed. I was running 2010/2008 side by side but I've since switched to a new box which only has 2010. Anyway, all working now. Thanks a lot for the help.